# Do 'zeros and poles' (with multiplicity) of a complex-valued function correspond to 'holes' of the de Rham cohomology of a punctured plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

The [following article](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-de-Rham-cohomology) gives an intuitive explanation of de Rham cohomology. In it, and other articles (such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form)) there is mention of the one-form $d\theta$ for $\theta=atan2(ky,kx)$ giving the de Rham cohomology of the punctured plane. Essentially, it gives the quotient of space of closed k-forms modulo exact ones, and is a way of counting the number of holes.

But, for the same $d\theta$ above, the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) is $2\pi i\oint d\theta$. Since this is closely tied to the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), it contributes to the statement of the principle, giving the number of zeros minus the number of poles of a function, with multiplicity.

First of all, am I right in saying that there is therefore a correspondence between the argument principle and the de Rham cohomology of the punctured plane?

If so, how can I intuitively understand the role of 'multiplicity', 'zeros' and 'poles' in terms of lingo from de Rham cohomology? For example, if I have a function that gives me a zero with multiplicity 2, is this equivalent to saying that I have '2 holes at the same point'? What about 'poles', then?
I guess I am asking how to equate the notion of 'holes' to 'zeros' and 'poles.

I understand this question might sound nonsensical, but I just have a very basic understanding of these concepts and first would like to develop an intuitive understanding.

Comment: You can get what you need out of this math.SE answer, more or less (modulo a proof of the argument principle from the residue theorem): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856010/closed-exact-forms-and-complex-functions/3856222#3856222

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you for that reference. Would you mind expanding on the 'multiplicity' part my question?

Comment: when you prove the argument principle from the residue theorem you show that the construction of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ has the effect of converting the multiplicity of a zero or pole to a residue. The residue corresponds to a scalar multiple of a generator in de Rham cohomology.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you. Would you be able to recommend any references that discuss the contents of your last comment? Also, if you want to write your comments as a brief answer I will gladly accept it as the solution. Thank you!